# Show a subview when button is pressed. (Something like view which appears when operating system Windows "start" button is pressed

Tags: iphone, subview

I want to show a subview that will contain list of menu when a UIbutton is pressed. Should I use vertical SegmentControl?
Thanks for any help in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to use vertical TabbarViewController.

First of all, go to the interface builder and drag a Button, connect the Button to an action method you declare in the .m file

let's said that the method is

```
- (IBAction) btnHandler :(id)sender {
}
```

then declare a new view and add it to your main view 
so the btnhandler method will look like this

```
- (IBAction) btnHandler :(id)sender {
     UIView *subview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 50, 320, 300)];
     //here add what ever you want to the new created view using the
     //[subview addSubview:(your Componant)];
     [self.view addSubview:subview];
}
```

please forgive me if i made a mistake, this is not tested code. i write it now in the browser.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your efforts.

Comment: welcome my friend. if you wanna any help in iPhone/iPad development, ask me XD

Answer (score 1):

If its an iPad application, maybe consider calling a UIPopOverController

Comment: I didn't mentioned it earlier, this app is for iPhone. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an Action Sheet if you're aiming for a native iOS look and feel.

Agree with the previous answer that a pop over is a great option if this is an iPad app.

You could go full custom of course with your own viewController which you can animate in from the top or bottom depending on your need.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1:
Design the view in your nib.

Option 2:
Have a separate view controller

You can use addSubView method to add the view when you press the UIButton

Answer (score 0):

```
Try below code that will help you.

- (void)viewDidLoad {
     UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [button setTitle:@"Show View" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 210.0, 160.0, 40.0);
    [self.view addSubview:button];

    [super viewDidLoad];

}

-(IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender
{
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 200, 300, 100)];
    view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    view.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    [self.view addSubview:view];
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your efforts.